# Android Virtual Device Manager Serato Error

Tags: plugins, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am following your tutorial "Running Your App">"Run on the Emulator". When I go to the "Android Virtual Device Manager" Select the AVD "My_First_AVD" I created and hit start, I am getting the following message:

Starting emulator for AVD 'My_First_AVD'
2013-02-21 22:43:22.504 emulator64-arm[302:80b] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2013-02-21 22:43:22.506 emulator64-arm[302:80b] Cannot find function pointer New_SHP_PlugIn for factory 834FC054-C1CC-11D6-BD01-00039315CD46 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x100d36560  (bundle, not loaded)

A black screen comes up with "Android" , but nothing else (I would imagine the "My First App" would come up with "Hello World") I am not sure why the emulator is looking at Serato for a plug in.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Jon

Comment: Did you ever solve this? i have the same problem! (i ended up just uninstalling serato with clean app and the error went away)